# How to use user defined keys for navigating in Slideshows?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, slideshows

How would I define, say < and >, or the left arrow key and right arrow key as keyboard shortcuts for moving forward and backward in slideshows?

Answer (score 6):

Evaluate one line once inside the notebook (or creating a button) will do:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
 NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", ">"} :> 
    FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollPageNext"], {"KeyDown", "<"} :> 
    FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollPagePrevious"]}]
```

or, using left and right arrows, but a bit more trickery to preserve normal arrow behaviour in the "Working" environment:

```
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions :> {"RightArrowKeyDown" :> 
     If[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] =!= 
       "SlideShow", 
      SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Next, Character], 
      FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollPageNext"]], 
    "LeftArrowKeyDown" :> 
     If[CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], ScreenStyleEnvironment] =!= 
       "SlideShow", 
      SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Character], 
      FrontEndTokenExecute["ScrollPagePrevious"]]}];
```

Interestingly enough the PageUp and PageDown keys always are already defined to navigate forward and backward, but one sometimes wants other keys in order to use a programmable (air)mouse.